# I am trying to connect a ViewSonic monitor by using two adapters in series without success--is it not possible to use two adapters in series?

Tags: usb, multiple-monitors, hdmi, vga

I have two monitors so that I can have a three-screen setup with my laptop. My laptop has an HDMI port that rarely works and has no VGA Port. My LG monitor requires an HDMI cable, while my ViewSonic monitor requires a VGA cable.  As a workaround, I have been using [a multi-port adapter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mC2VB.jpg) to connect my HDMI cable for my LG monitor through the USB-C port. I have also been able to use a [VGA to USB-C adapter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z66t9.jpg) to connect my ViewSonic monitor to my laptop through the same USB-C port. However, because there's only one USB-C port, I haven't been able to connect both monitors simultaneously.

Then I thought of a [possible workaround](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQFq6.jpg)--what if I connect both monitors through the same port by using the multi-port adapter? The ViewSonic connects via a VGA cable to the VGA to USB-C adapter, which I then plugged into the multi-port adapter, while I connected the LG through an HDMI cable to that same multi-port adapter.

This experiment failed--the LG monitor displayed just fine while the ViewSonic monitor displayed a "No Signal" message on the screen.

I determined that it's possible to plug in two devices into the multi-port adapter because I added a USB chip for my Bluetooth mouse simultaneous with the HDMI cable for the LG monitor--the LG monitor once again displayed perfectly.

So is it just impossible to hook up a VGA-based monitor with two adapters in series? Do I need a direct adapter (VGA to USB-C or VGA to USB-A) for example?

For now, I'll just buy a VGA to USB-A adapter because I do have functional USB-A ports on the computer. I was just hoping to save some money and I'm also trying to understand better how ports, adapters, and computer hardware interact.